# Why is translocation of food in the phloem still a debate?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology

I currently take tertiary-high school biology and I am taught that translocation of food in the phloem occurs by the pressure flow hypothesis.
I would like to ask why it is still a hypothesis, and what are arguments against it. If possible are there any scientific literature or journals for me to chew on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The wikipedia page provides some of the opposing arguments, but doesn't necessarily source them.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_Flow_Hypothesis